# Persistent session in glassfish behind nginx proxy

Tags: java, session, nginx, proxy, glassfish

I am running a glassfish webserver behind a nginx proxy (which resolves domains). I want to store @SessionScoped data on the Webserver.
My problem is, that nginx opens a new session everytime it connects to glassfish and that session is in no way connected to the client. The client itself has an active session on nginx.

Glassfish seems to be aware of the fact, that something is wrong with the way the sessions are being handled. It manipulates links within the application to keep the session intact:
".../ProxyTest/page2.jsf;jsessionid=4372da9b75a2043875c73b12f998"
It does not do that if I connect directly to the webserver(without the proxy)
This behaviour is totally unacceptable to me, I need that manipulation gone, but still have the session.

I would like to have an individual and persistent session on glassfish for every user that connects to it via the proxy without having to pass the sessionID in the url.

nginx does set the cookie, but the browser does not send it back. I'm assuming the cookie is formatted correctly:

```
Set-Cookie:"JSESSIONID=84c5e4e43538da045cc1d8f2a629; Path=/ProxyTest; HttpOnly"
```

my nginx settings:
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  www.abc.ch;

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header customer abc;
    access_log off;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081/ProxyTest/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_redirect     off;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
```

}

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.onlineshop.ch;

location / {
    proxy_set_header customer onlineshop;
    access_log off;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081/ProxyTest/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_redirect     off;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

}
```

The problem is now, that the browser does not send back the cookie, or for some reason it doesn't get throught to the server. On every request the server generates a new session ID. Confirming that is that data stored in a @SessionScoped bean gets lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It helps if you post your NGINX proxy config. A basic reverse proxy config looks like this:

```
...
http {
    ....
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  www.yourdomain.com;

        location / {
            access_log off;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            ...
        }
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Major mistake on my side, I've deleted the edit. It seems to work now. Thank you so much. I'm not exactly shure why it works, the browser doesn't set the cookie on a second request.

Comment: Mistake again, it does not work. Edited die answer again to describe the new problem

Comment: You forward / to /ProxyTest/ . The application server assumes that its cookie path is /ProxyTest/ and sets the cookie only under that path. Your browser only sees that you are at / and doesn't send the cookie for /ProxyTest. Relocate your application on the app server to / or also use /ProxyTest in Nginx.

Comment: When I set ´server_name  www.onlineshop.ch/ProxyTest;´ nginx complains that it contains suspicious symbols.

Comment: Yes, the server name is the domain not a path (no /). Just type your domain and as location use /. In your browser then type /ProxyTest

Comment: It seems to work now, but I'm suspicious, I've had too many false positives. Thank you so very much!!! :D

Comment: `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081/ProxyTest/;` has to be `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;`